# Importing Turicreate gives me error No module named 'turicreate.cython.cy_unity'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, turi-create

While importing turicreate i get below error in jupyter notebook:

No module named 'turicreate.cython.cy_unity'

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the package. Not sure what i am doing wrong here. I am using windows 10 64 bit machine and Python 3.7.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TC does not support Python 3.7, the latest supported version is 3.6

You need to configure Python 3.6 virtual environment, which is easy to do with Anaconda.

Check out this article about details on setting up TC and other ML packages - https://medium.com/@maxim.volgin/machine-learning-compass-fcee3d9ac3b3